# Where are the files downloaded to when using `apt-get download` command?

Tags: apt

I want to know the storage location of `sudo apt-get download` command in Ubuntu.

I searched in the archives folder but its not there.

Answer (score 6):

It will be downloaded to your current directory. E.g.

1. Run

   ```
   apt-get download packagename
   ```
2. Note the output, e.g.

   ```
   Get:1 Downloading passwd 1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu4.1 [1,073 kB]
   Fetched 1,073 kB in 0s (4,792 kB/s)
   ```
3. List the files:

   ```
   ls packagename*.deb
   ```

   returns in my example

   ```
   passwd_4.1.5.1-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb
   ```

Note that as it just fetches a package and drops it in your current directory, you don't need `sudo`.

Comment: The same is true for `apt-get source <package-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

From [`apt-get(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html), emphasis by me:

> #### download
>
> download will download the given binary package *into the current directory*.